# Arabic Letters in Oracle Apex IR Chart

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, apexcharts

I have an IR that display data in Arabic and English language.

The IR data view display data properly but when I change to chart view with label that contains Arabic letters it display labels of chart with foreign letters as shown in image.

Note:- Apex version 18.2

[image: Apex IR in chart view]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this error on apex.oracle.com. Can you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution that was because the `NLS_Charecterset` of database must be `AL32UTF8` this could solve the problem.

Another way to solve that is to upgrade apex to 19.1 or later